# Java Class.forName() from distant directory

Tags: java, class, classpath, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I am currently loading Java classes using `Class.forName()` to load it.

```
clazz = Class.forName("interfaces.MyClass");
```

But now I want to load classes from different directory, I have tried to set classpath by

```
clazz = Class.forName("-cp \"C:/dir\" distantinterfaces.DistantClass");
```

With no success and `ClassNotFoundException`. Full path to distant class is:

```
C:/dir/distantinterfaces/DistantClass.class
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) for this.  The code might be something along the lines of:

```
File f = new File("C:/dir");
URL[] cp = {f.toURI().toURL()};
URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(cp);
Class clazz = urlcl.loadClass("distantinterfaces.DistantClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

Either the directory is in the classpath, and you can use `Class.forName()` (which only accepts fuly qualified name classes, and not `-cp` command line options), or it's not in the classpath and you should then use a custom class loader.

You're not saying what you really want to do (why are you loading classes dynamically), but your best bet is to have the directory in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of ClassLoader which is aware of the directory with classes. See [stackoverflow questions tagged urlclassloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlclassloader).