# Use local jars in JNLP program

Tags: java, jar, classloader, jnlp, java-web-start

I have java program that needs many jars. Now I want run it via JNLP. Jars are from client software, that user have installed. I do not want to include hundreds jars in JNLP file and download it.

For example in my JNLP/Swing application user write path to software with jars and my program load jars and use it.

How use local jars (for example in system PATH) in my JNLP program?

Comment: Sure, but it will require a fully trusted app.  If your user is able/agreeable to run that, you'd do it pretty much as shown in this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16335305/418556).  *"user write path to software"*  Better to offer them a `JFileChooser` filtered Jar files. ;)

Comment: Not a duplicate (the linked question is not related to JNLP.)

Comment: Why would you want to do this though? JNLP was designed to be independent of locally-installed software.  I would imagine a manually-installed app would be better in this situation.

Comment: Andrew, user don't know which jars are required, so I think specify the directory of the program (client tools with jars) is a better option.
@finnw Unfortunately I must do it this way..

Comment: OK I get it.  Nevertheless the accepted answer to the question I linked provides the answer for plain desktop runnable Jar or JNLP app.  Just swap the `"C:/dir"` for `"your/path/here"`