# how to identified class if including package from another directory

Tags: java, class

from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335305/java-class-forname-from-distant-directory), i using class loader to identified class from other directory

```
File dir=new File ("D:\\dirclass")
fulldir = new File (dir+"\\myclass");
filename = new StringTokenizer(fulldir.getName(), ".").nextToken();
URL[] checkclass = 
{
    dir.toURI().toURL()
};
URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(checkclass);
Class cls = urlcl.loadClass(filename);
```

this is worked if class without package.

but if class with package, failed to running.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packclass (wrongname: dirclass\packclass)
```

is there any other way ?

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What *does* happen?

Comment: failed identified class that including package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the fully qualified names of classes to the `ClassLoader`, for example:

```
Class cls = urlcl.loadClass("com.mypackage.MyClass");
```